# How can i create sub directories within a directory?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, directory, directory-structure, mkdir

I am trying to make a photo organizer with a zsh shell script. But i am having trouble creating sub directories within each main directory(based on date). Currently the script starts from a folder i created and gets one argument(the file it needs to edit, hence the first cd $1). Secondly, i do some name changing which is irrelevant for my question. Next i create a directory for each date and move the photo to the correct directory.

The issue is, i want to loop through each date folder and make 2 new sub directories(jpg and raw). But when i run the code i get an error that there is no such file or directory..

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/zsh.
cd $1
for i in *.JPG;
do
        mv $i $(basename $i .JPG).jpg;
done
        
for i in *;
do
       d=$(date -r "$i" +%d-%m-%Y)
       mkdir -p "$d"
       mv -- "$i" "$d/";
done
for d in *;
do
        cd $d
        for i in *.jpg;
        do
                mkdir -p "jpg"
                mv -- "$i" "jpg";
        done

        for i in *.NEF;
        do
                mkdir -p "raw"
                mv -- "$i" "raw";
        done
done
```

If anyone knows where i made a mistake that would be really helpfull since i have no clue what goes wrong and there is no debugger in nano as far as i know.

**Error**

```
➜  files sh test2.sh sdcard1 

test2.sh: line 16: cd: 05-03-2022: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.jpg to jpg/*.jpg: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.NEF to raw/*.NEF: No such file or directory
test2.sh: line 16: cd: 23-10-2021: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.jpg to jpg/*.jpg: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.NEF to raw/*.NEF: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the error *exactly*? Is it about `zsh.`? Are you sure the dot at the end of the shebang is right?

Comment: It appears that the script works on the first directory on which it has to create sub folders and mv the file to it. But once it gets to the second one see the error above.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72417034/7552

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted (…)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310)

Comment: The cross-posting is bad form, but the question is not off-topic for unix I think (it's a question on shell scripting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in *;
do
        cd $d
```

As far as I can tell this is the error.  You've created a loop over your directories `d`.  You cd into `$d`.  But your loop never cd's back out

```
        done
        cd ..
done
```

So on the second iteration with the second `$d`, you're still in the first subdir, which of course does not contain the second `$d` as a subsubdir.

Incidently you're ordering by increasing day, `%d-%m-%Y`.  You're free to do that of course, but you might find ordering by year organises the dirs more tidily, `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: Great thank a lot!! :)